# isotope sortBy simply not functioning as it should

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using the following as set up for the page (the isotope masonry system works perfectly by the way, just not the sort):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#wall');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.block2',
    getSortData : {
      name : function ( $elem ) {
        return $elem.find('.name').text();
      }
    },
    getSortData : {
      site : function ( $elem ) {
        return $elem.find('.site').text();
      }
    }
  });

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.block2',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
      }
    },
    // call Isotope as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

with example data:

```
<div class="block2">
<li class="list_item">
<div class="list_item_view">
<div class="list_item_name" title="JETS Journey 2011" style=font-size:11px;>
<span class="name">Jets Journey 2011</span></div>
<div class="site"><span class="site">abc.com</span></div></div></div>

<div class="block2">
<li class="list_item">
<div class="list_item_view">
<div class="list_item_name" title="Killers" style=font-size:11px;>
<span class="name">Killers</span></div>
<div class="site"><span class="site">ydc.com</span></div></div></div>

<div class="block2">
<li class="list_item">
<div class="list_item_view">
<div class="list_item_name" title="Best yet" style=font-size:11px;>
<span class="name">Best yet</span></div>
<div class="site"><span class="site">cagey.com</span></div></div></div>
```

And to call the sort changes:

```
<a href=#sortBy=name>name</a> <a href=#sortBy=site>site</a>
```

But simply nothing happens when i click the sort links - am I missing a simple point somewhere?

Comment: Instead of pasting code we can't run, why don't you set it up in a jsfiddle? Then you and others can try things out live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rz4pC/) for a working example. Or [sorting the first one out](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/8QkEw/) and [sort ascending and descending](http://jsfiddle.net/circlecube/LNRzZ/).

Comment: Many thanks for that but that's filtering, not sorting. Will use jsfiddle in future, good idea.